# Fantic Caballero 500 Scrambler Loses Power

Tags: engine, motorcycle, power-loss, fantic, caballero

I have a Fantic caballero 500 scrambler (single cylinder), little over 2,000kms, so relatively new. The bike loses power (as if there is no fuel being pumped to the system), around 4,000 rpm, and will come to a stop. Pressing the clutch and readjusting the gear will sometimes help shake it back to life. When that "choking" happens, if I keep a steady gas, it will then sometimes jump to its correct power until loses power again. I had the check engine light on for a brief period of time but then it went away. I added cooling fluid to the expansion box (it was below minimum level) but I noticed a few leakages (although I had not added more than the max line), but I pumped out some fluid and for a long time, the choking did not happen. I assumed that was the reason. I recently had another power cut, no leakages, so I don't have a clue. Fantic shares maintenance services with Ducati in Istanbul, and it is a nightmare to get a reservation. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!